# How to update the user information

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to build an additional information that will be shown in the profile of the user. So if the user info haven't been updated they will be asked to up their profile, it will only be shown to the profile owner. then it will show "this user haven't updated their profile info to display" to the other users that view the profile. If the the profile is updated, the info will be shown in their profile and shown to any user that views the profile. How can i develop this?

This is what i tried so far located at the profile

```
buildUserInfo() {
     bool isProfileOwner = currentUserId == widget.profileId;
     if(isProfileOwner) {
                      return Column(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                 children: <Widget>[
                   Container(
                     alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                     child: ListTile(
                       trailing: IconButton(
                         icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                         onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context, 
                         MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Information())
                       )),
                       title: Text(
                         'Update profile info'
                       ),
                     ),
                   ),
                   Divider(),
                   ListTile(
                     contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                     leading: Icon( Icons.my_location,),
                     title:Text(
                       currentUser.address,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          leading: Icon( Icons.location_on,),
          title: Text(
            currentUser.location,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          leading: Icon( Icons.school,),
          title: Text(
            currentUser.school,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          leading: Icon( Icons.work,),
          title: Text(
            currentUser.work,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ListTile(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          leading: Icon( Icons.contact_mail,),
          title: Text(
            currentUser.contactAddress,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
        ),
       
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.timelapse,
                size: 20.0,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
              child: Text(timeago.format(timestamp)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
   } else {
     return Text('');
   }
  }
```

Comment: Huh?  Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  THis question is too broad.

Comment: Please use code format for code and outputs. I think that will improve your question a lot.